# Setup mutt to read through a threaded message and then return to the email index

Tags: command-line, terminal, mutt

I have begun using mutt (terminal email client) recently and I have it setup very nicely and easy to use. My only gripe is that sometimes it is difficult to tell when I transition from one thread to the next.

Is it possible to setup the bindings such that moving to the next-undeleted message would check if the next-undeleted message is in the same thread, and if that check is false it returns to the index or throws an error?

For example, I currently have

```
bind pager <down> next-undeleted
bind pager } next-subthread
```

Is there a more advanced function call that could perform this check? I haven't been able to find much on how to perform more complex function calls with such checks while checking out the manual. Any help would be appreciated.